# Why a MKPolyline doesn't show on the MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkoverlay

I'm pretty new on programmin to develop iphone applications and i would like to know why the MKPolyline that I create with 2 MKMapPoints doesn't appears in the MKMapView that I insert on my view.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];


MKMapPoint * pointsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)*4);

CLLocationCoordinate2D punto1;
punto1.latitude =39.468502;
punto1.longitude =-0.398469;


MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = punto1;
annotationPoint.title = @"Point 1";

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
annotationPoint2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.472312,-0.386453);
annotationPoint2.title = @"Point 2";


[map addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
[map addAnnotation:annotationPoint2];


pointsArray[0]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(punto1);

pointsArray[1]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.467011,-0.390015));

pointsArray[2]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.469926,-0.392118));

pointsArray[3]= MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.472312,-0.386453));

routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:4];

free(pointsArray);

[map addOverlay:routeLine];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.467011,-0.392515), 1100, 1100);
[map setRegion:region];

[self.view insertSubview:map atIndex:0];

}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay

{

MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

MKPolylineView  * routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];


routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];

routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

routeLineView.lineWidth = 3;

overlayView = routeLineView;

return overlayView;

}
```

The annotations are OK and they show correctly on the map.
Hope someone can help, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `MKPolyline` doesn't show because the map's `delegate` is not set.

The `viewForOverlay` *delegate* method won't get called if the map's `delegate` property is not set.  Because the delegate method is never called, the `MKPolylineView` never gets created, etc...

After creating the `MKMapView`, set its `delegate`:

```
map = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
map.delegate = self;  // <-- add this
```

I'd like to mention a few other unrelated points:

- Since you are putting `MKMapPoint` values in the `pointsArray`, the `malloc` should use `sizeof(MKMapPoint)` instead of `sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D)`.  It happens to work with the wrong code because both structs happen to be the same size.  But you should still use the right code.
- `MKPolyline` also has a `polylineWithCoordinates:count:` method so you can pass `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instead of `MKMapPoint` structs.  This can be easier to read, understand, and avoids having to convert from coordinates to mappoints.
- The `MKPolylineView` uses `strokeColor` only so setting the `fillColor` for it does nothing.
- In the `viewForOverlay` delegate method, it's much better practice to use the `overlay` parameter that is passed into the method instead of the externally declared `routeLine`.  This will be extremely important if you want to add more than one overlay.  You would also first check what kind of class `overlay` is and then create the appropriate view for it.